# Emscripten allowed alignments for different datatypes

Tags: alignment, emscripten

What is allowed and what not in terms of alignment for emscripten?

I guess an int should have an address with the lower 2 bits == 0.

How about a char? Should it also have the lower two bits == 0 for it's address? or can it be at all addresses?

How about a double or int64_t? Are the lowest two bits == 0 enough or should it be the lowest 3 bits == 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine just told me:
The requirement is to follow standard C alignment rule for types. Which says that each type should be aligned at an address that is a multiple of the size of the type in question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86

floats are always stored as 32 bit floats in emscripten. -s PRECISE_FP32=0 or 2 just does the calculations in 64 bits but storage is still done as 32 bit floats.